# I don't know whats causing this error , require is not defined

Tags: react-native

React Native android app was working fine until it decided not to work. This is the error it shows when I debug otherwise it just says Unknown error which is really annoying. I have no idea what is causing this error but I'm thinking this has to do with plugin-proposal-decorators that I'm using. Has anyone faced this issue before?

[image]

My babel.config.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', '@babel/preset-env'],
  plugins: [['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }]]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtCZb.png)

[image]

Comment: do you have any `require` instead of `import` in your components?

Comment: @NaeimFard Nope! checked my whole project

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose" : true }]
  ]
```

You have to use another plugin `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` to make compatibility with presets and must **enable loose mode** of class properties.

Comment: have you maintained the order of plugins like ```@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators``` come before ```@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties```.

Comment: Yes! But I'm not sure if that's what causing the issue because I have used proposal decorators before and never ran into this

Comment: Ok it is proposal decorators. I just disabled the proposal decorators and proposal class properties and the app is working fine. That means the issue is within proposal decorators itself. I think I should open an issue on their github